# Concatenate a dataframe with a cyclic shifted subset of its columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a pandas df

```
id    v1       v2
 1    20.1    30.1
 2    32.0    40
 3    11.0    12.012
```

I want to add 2 more columns such that my dataframe looks like:

```
id    v1       v2     v1_new    v2_new
 1    20.1    30.1    32.0      40
 2    32.0    40      11.0      12.012
 3    11.0    12.012  20.1      30.1
```

i.e adding the next consecutive rows as a column in previous row , and for the last row, add a column filling values of the first row.

Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.roll`

```
In [793]: df.assign(v1_new=np.roll(df.v1, -1), v2_new=np.roll(df.v2, -1))
Out[793]:
   id    v1      v2  v1_new  v2_new
0   1  20.1  30.100    32.0  40.000
1   2  32.0  40.000    11.0  12.012
2   3  11.0  12.012    20.1  30.100
```

Comment: Nice... something new.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, you can implement a generic version of `np.roll` using `df.iloc` and`pd.concat`:

```
In [521]: pd.concat([df1, df1.iloc[:, -2:].transform(np.roll, shift=-1).add_suffix('_new')], 1)
Out[521]: 
   id    v1      v2  v1_new  v2_new
0   1  20.1  30.100    32.0  40.000
1   2  32.0  40.000    11.0  12.012
2   3  11.0  12.012    20.1  30.100
```

This is a more general version of [John Galt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45838075/4909087), and works if you want to roll an arbitrary number of columns.